# Nodejs cluster workers with "dynamic" code

Tags: javascript, node.js, cluster-computing

Good Evening/Afternoon/Morning, so I ran into some sort of issue with the cluster module from nodejs.

So first of all my current situation:
 I´m running a nodejs "script" which has a "master" part and a "worker" part, meaning the master part fetching data from a website and sending it to the workers to "deliver" via websocket to visitors.

So is there any way to sort of "dynamicly" reload the workers code without restarting the master itself ? ( e.g. stopping a worker and starting it again with new code ? ), I previously thought about using "exec" to start a "worker" file basicly splitting "master" and "worker" completly in terms of files, but would I be able to use functions like "process.send" if I did so ?

Regards

Comment: there are lifecycle events you can use from either angle (worker/master) to know when to spawn more workers when one dies/suicides.

Comment: yea i know when a worker "spawns" or "dies", but thats not what i wanted to know. My problem here is if there is any way to dynamicly reload a workers code if something changes inside.

Comment: if workers self-respawn, then terminating them upon a code change should be harmless. maybe fs.watch is the trigger you're looking for.

Comment: yea fs.watch seems to do what i wanted, one more question doe. is it possible to access the "master" process from file "worker.js" if it is loaded with exec "worker.js" ( communication between them etc "process.send"... )

Comment: yes: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_send_message_sendhandle_callback